# Word VBA highlighting text

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlighting

I'm generating some security report in Microsoft Word - importing SOAP xml requests and responses...

I want to automate this process as much as I can and I need to highlight some text in these requests/responses. How to do that? In general I need to highlight non-standart inputs in requests (every time different - bad data types and so on) and fault strings in responses (in majority looks like this `<faultstring>some error</faultstring>`).

Heres code Im trying:

```
    Sub BoldBetweenQuotes()
' base for a quotes finding macro
    Dim blnSearchAgain As Boolean
    ' move to start of doc
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
     ' start of loop
    Do
        ' set up find of first of quote pair
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "<faultstring>"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Execute
        End With
        If Selection.Find.Found Then
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            ' switch on selection extend mode
            Selection.Extend
            ' find second quote of this pair
            Selection.Find.Text = "</faultstring>"
            Selection.Find.Execute
            If Selection.Find.Found Then
                Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(Selection.Find.Text)
                ' make it bold
                Selection.Font.Bold = True
                Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                blnSearchAgain = True
            Else
                blnSearchAgain = False
            End If
        Else
            blnSearchAgain = False
        End If
    Loop While blnSearchAgain = True
End Sub
```

It highlights just the first faultstring, but other appearences stay unformated nad I dont know why.... Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this is to work with multiple `Range` objects. Think of a `Range` as being like an invisible selection, with the important difference that, while there can be but one `Selection` object there can be multiple `Range` objects in your code.

I've adapted your code, adding three `Range` objects: one for the entire document; one for finding the starting tag; one for finding the end tag. The `Duplicate` property is used to "copy" one `Range` from another (this due to an oddity in Word if you `Set` one `Range` to another, which links them).

For clarity I also added a couple more Boolean test values for your `If`comparisons. In my experience, it's more reliable to pick up the "success" directly from `Execute` than to rely on `Find.Found` after-the-fact.

```
Sub BoldBetweenQuotes()
    ' base for a quotes finding macro
    Dim blnSearchAgain As Boolean
    Dim blnFindStart As Boolean
    Dim blnFindEnd As Boolean
    Dim rngFind As word.Range
    Dim rngFindStart As word.Range
    Dim rngFindEnd As word.Range

    Set rngFind = ActiveDocument.content
    Set rngFindStart = rngFind.Duplicate
    Do
        ' set up find of first of quote pair
        With rngFindStart.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "<faultstring>"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .wrap = wdFindStop
            blnFindStart = .Execute
        End With
        If blnFindStart Then
            rngFindStart.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Set rngFindEnd = rngFindStart.Duplicate
            rngFindEnd.Find.Text = "</faultstring>"
            blnFindEnd = rngFindEnd.Find.Execute
            If blnFindEnd Then
                rngFindStart.End = rngFindEnd.Start
                ' make it bold
                rngFindStart.Font.Bold = True
                rngFindStart.Start = rngFindEnd.End
                rngFindStart.End = rngFind.End
                blnSearchAgain = True
            Else
                blnSearchAgain = False
            End If
        Else
            blnSearchAgain = False
        End If
    Loop While blnSearchAgain = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code, you described something I didnt know, learned something new... :) Could there be a mistake in a cycle? Even my edited code keeps cycling and Word freezes for a while every time I start the macro....

Comment: @MichalJanošec you can debug your code and check where it keeps looping by hitting "F8" in your macro or just set a break point.

Comment: @BrunoBieri Thanks, did that now and it keeps cycling and making bold just the first appearance of text between faultstring tags... I think I have a mistake in moving start of the search after the appearance, but Im little bit lost in all those findStart.End findEnd.Start things :D

Comment: @MichalJanošec I did test this, with multiple <faultstring> tag pairs, before I posted. You should be able to copy/paste my code and it should run. Did you change anything? If yes, why?

Comment: @CindyMeister Hello there, I did test it now in a new sheet and it works like a charm, but it doesn't work and freezes everytime in the main sheet and I don't know why... Could it be because of that I'm importing xmls as fields in MS Word? Im automatically updating fields on open with this `Sub AutoOpen()
    With Options
        .UpdateFieldsAtPrint = True
        .UpdateLinksAtPrint = True
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub`

Comment: @MichalJanošec It's very difficult for me to tell, given the little information it's possible for you to provide in Comments. My advice would be to open a new Question, focussing on this problem. For example, I don't know what you mean by "new sheet" or "main sheet". Also provide info about "importing xmls as fields". And include the AutoOpen code (that shouldn't be a problem, but...)

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks l'll do that and thanks for the code you provided :)